# how to get android fingerprint data from the result set and save it in mysql

Tags: android, fingerprint

i'm developing an android application with fingerprint authentication.so i need to implement register and login function through the fingerprint.

in my scenario i no need use passwords. i use fingerprint instead of the password.

i implemented simple fingerprint function,but i can't get any result form it (i mean no any fingerprint image or any data from result set).

so how i achieve this,is android provide user fingerprint data to the third party apps?

and i need to know is my flow is correct or not? and is this practical way ? or any one have any suggestion for this task ..

Thank you cheers,

Comment: I think it is not possible to get fingerprint data since it is not stored as Image. And after android 5.0 google add more security feature for such data.
You can get authentication using : https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth
but you can't get figureprint data

Comment: @Deepak thanks for your comment, yes i read lots of articles regarding of this..but my problem is how other app verify user with fingerprint and communicate with APIs,how they verified user from the server side without any password?

Comment: use this link : https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth

Comment: you cannot get any response of data form the mobile biometric ... if you want to do the exact flow.. then you have to use an external finger print sensor so from there you can get the data and upload to server....but user always have to use an external sensor so not so practical